# What's best protocol used in GPS-server connection?

Tags: java, gps, nmea

I want to build a GPS application depends on using cell phones trackers and a server used to receive the results and informs it. as i want to use a standard protocol in dealing with the connection between the server and the GPS tracker exists in the cell phone.
After a lot of search i found three available protocols:

1- [NMEA 0183](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183).

2- [SiRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SiRF).

3- [MTK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaTek).

I want to know the best one of these protocols in order to use, or if there is any other important protocols that i didn't discover.

Comment: it's a what-best-to-choose question and it's not that vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- NMEA 0183:

not suitable: bad specified, sucht that there is much room for interpretation, differnet GPS chip manufacturers behave differently, further: needs to many bytes, because not a binary protcoll, it was designed to be human readable, too

2- SIRF: 
SIRF binary: better, but like NMEA desigend for CHIP to App communication not for app to server. (Redundant fields like "time" when using multiple messages)

MTK i dont know.

There is also ubx binary (U-blox) chips. similar to SIRF, but still desogned for chipp to app communication.

I personally would design my own format for binary GPS packets, picking the atributes that I need.
and send that packets via std protocol like http.